# Webkit-text-stroke not working on mobile

Tags: css, webkit, font-awesome

I am currently using webkit-text-stroke to make my font-awesome icons look thinner

CSS

```
.arrow:after { font-family: $font-awesome; content:'\f054'; -webkit-text-stroke: 3px white; float: right; }
```

It works perfectly when I view it on my laptop (I am using Chrome). However, when I view my website on mobile (iPhone, using Chrome as well), the webkit-text-stroke css properties does not seem to be applied. The icons are still on its default thickness (No stroke). Any solutions? Or maybe an alternative to making the icons thinner which will work on mobile as well?

Comment: please provide a working jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ":after", use the class as shown, it will work.

```
.fa-arrow-right {
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px orange;
}
```

Comment: Tried this but it still doesn't work... Webkit-text-stroke does not seem to work on mobile